# on deploying egg file in scrapyd server then {"status": "error", "message": "IndexError: list index out of range"}

Tags: python, scrapyd

Deploying to project "projectname" in http://127.0.0.1:6800/addversion.json

```
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "IndexError: list index out of range"}
```

when I create egg file , and deploy in scrapyd server , then such kind of error comes , please if someone have any solution give me. thanks in advance

Comment: Any code? the error message indicates that your are accessing a non-existing index

Comment: but when first time I did this , then  it deploy and run  properly , but now it will not,  in my spider list approx 300 spiders ,is number of large spiders  creating problem , reply pls

Answer (score 1):

please check your argument parameter which used in yout code

```
import os
 s_file = sys.argv[2]
```

please check your agrument paramter
 or check your code should not be outside to your class