# scrapyd {"status":"error", "message": "Use \"scrapy\" to see available commands"

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy, scrapyd

When attempting to deploy my project to scrapyd using the following command:

```
scrapyd-deploy test2 -p NOAA
```

or, when attempting to run my spider that I created:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=test -d spider=myspider
```

I get the following output:

```
Packing version 1478644677 
Deploying to project "test" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json 
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "Use \"scrapy\" to see available
commands",  "node_name": "osboxes"}
```

The following files appear empty when I check them:

```
/var/log/scrapyd/scrapyd.log 
/var/log/scrapyd/scrapyd.out
/var/log/scrapyd/scrapyd.err
```

I referenced this answer :[on deploying egg file in scrapyd server then {"status": "error", "message": "IndexError: list index out of range"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838718/on-deploying-egg-file-in-scrapyd-server-then-status-error-message-ind)

But it is a different output, he had an index problem.

With my error I think something is wrong with the spider itself? IT appears that it deploys, but it can't initiate a spider.

I installed scrapyd as instructed. This is my scrapy.cfg file:

```
[settings]
default = NOAA.settings

[deploy:test2] 
url = http://localhost:6800/ 
project = NOAA
```

running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I use: cd myprojectdir/myspider/ && sudo scrapyd-deploy default -p NOAA

Comment: Even when I navigate to my spider folder and run that command, i get the same error. I did change the [deploy:test2] in my scrapy.cfg to just [deploy] so that the default will work. Same error.

Comment: My scrapy.cfg file looks like this but on 5 lines: [settings]
default = myspider.settings
[deploy]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = myspider

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about that. My scrapy.cfg file is similar. I edited my original question to have that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

My /etc/scrapyd/conf.d/000-default (the configuration file) was empty for some reason...

1) I filled the file with this information from: http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#config

```
[scrapyd]
eggs_dir    = eggs
logs_dir    = logs
items_dir   =
jobs_to_keep = 5
dbs_dir     = dbs
max_proc    = 0
max_proc_per_cpu = 4
finished_to_keep = 100
poll_interval = 5
http_port   = 6800
debug       = off
runner      = scrapyd.runner
application = scrapyd.app.application
launcher    = scrapyd.launcher.Launcher

[services]
schedule.json     = scrapyd.webservice.Schedule
cancel.json       = scrapyd.webservice.Cancel
addversion.json   = scrapyd.webservice.AddVersion
listprojects.json = scrapyd.webservice.ListProjects
listversions.json = scrapyd.webservice.ListVersions
listspiders.json  = scrapyd.webservice.ListSpiders
delproject.json   = scrapyd.webservice.DeleteProject
delversion.json   = scrapyd.webservice.DeleteVersion
listjobs.json     = scrapyd.webservice.ListJobs
```

2) Restarted the service by doing **ctrl + c** on the terminal window running scrapyd, then typing the command **scrapyd**.

3) Re-ran the previously stated command (sudo is important):

```
sudo scrapyd-deploy test -p NOAA
```

4) success!

```
{"status": "ok", "project": "NOAA", "version": "1478702964", "spiders": 3, "node_name": "osboxes"}
```